# How to trigger a form submit in child component with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a Form component like this:

```
var React = require('react'),
  ReactRedux = require('react-redux');


var Form = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <form onsubmit={this.onsubmit} action={this.props.action}>
      {this.props.children}
      </form>
    );
  },
  // Method for parent component to call
  submit: function() {
    // do submission and return Promise so caller can take actions
  },
  onsubmit: function(e) {
    // validation, make requests, etc
  }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state;
}

module.exports = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Form);
```

Inside my render of a component I have `<Form  id="paymentform" ref="form" action="/self">`.

I can't do `this.refs.form.submit();` because `this.refs.form` points to the Connector. As I understand it, Connectors are the funnels for reducers to update props, however doing that can't trigger a call to `submit`.

The use case is basically to have the form submit from another action, which will kick off what the Form component is supposed to do such as validation and XHR requests.

I can do `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.form).submit()` but that doesn't answer the actual question of hitting a component method from outside.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the wrapped component instance, if necessary, [with `getWrappedInstance`](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/f9dfe461b730530c1a04061d6018540173efd5d1/src/components/createConnect.js#L197):

```
this.refs.form.getWrappedInstance().submit()
```

Comment: @DaveStein Hm, it used to be but now I don't see it.

Comment: If only their Slack wasn't overloaded so I could ask :D

Comment: @DaveStein :) I've [opened a PR](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/pull/142) to add it back to the docs.