# redux-form: trigger Form onSubmit after Input onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a simple set of radio buttons inside a redux-form. I need the onChange event of the radio button group to trigger the `onSubmit` event of the form.

I'm using redux-form v5.3.1

### Setup

**RadioFormContainer.js**

```js
class RadioFormContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const {submit} = this.props;
    return (
      <RadioForm submit={submit} />
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    submit: function(values, dispatch) {
      // API call after validation
    }
  }
};
```

**RadioForm.js**

```js
class RadioForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      submit, // custom post-validation handler
      // via redux form decorator:
      handleSubmit,
      submitting
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <input {...radioField}
               checked={radioField.value == "one"}
               type="radio"
               value="one"
               disabled={submitting} />
        <input {...radioField}
               checked={radioField.value == "two"}
               type="radio"
               value="two"
               disabled={submitting} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

### Attempted implementations, not working

**1. Call `handleSubmit` from `componentWillReceiveProps` on the `RadioForm`**

kyleboyle's [proposal here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/362#issuecomment-164013479) simply doesn't work. When I call `nextProps.handleSubmit` from `componentWillReceiveProps`, I get [this familiar error](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/190), `Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop`

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.dirty && nextProps.valid) {
    let doubleDirty = false;
    Object.keys(nextProps.fields).forEach(key => {
      if (nextProps.fields[key].value !== this.props.fields[key].value) {
        doubleDirty = true;
      }
    });
    if (doubleDirty) {
      nextProps.handleSubmit();
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Call `submit` on `RadioForm` from the `onChange` handler**

erikras [proposes this here.](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/67#issuecomment-140082130) But it doesn't work for me because it would skip validation.

```js
<input // ...
       onChange={(event) => {
          radioField.handleChange(event); // update redux state
          this.submit({ myField: event.target.value });
       }} />
```

I think Bitaru ([same thread](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/67#issuecomment-140117789)) is trying to say the same thing in his reply, but I'm not sure. Calling `onSubmit` for me causes the exception `Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.onSubmit is not a function`

**3. Call `submit` on the form via `this.refs`**

This causes the form to actually submit, totally skipping redux-form

Per: [How to trigger a form submit in child component with Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000354/how-to-trigger-a-form-submit-in-child-component-with-redux)

```js
<input // ...
       onChange={(event) => {
         radioField.onChange(event);
         this.refs.radioForm.submit();
       }} />
```

Comment: Does this https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/714 help?

Comment: You should use onSubmit function when you export your RadioForm like this `export default reduxForm({
  form: 'remoteSubmit',  // a unique identifier for this form
  onSubmit: submit       // submit function must be passed to onSubmit
})(RemoteSubmitForm)' https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/remotesubmit/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add an hidden submit button

```
<input ref="submit" type="submit" style="display: none;"/>
```

and the radio button onChange will call refs.submit.click() ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your second mentioned approach would work, if you have a field level validation and access to the error and touched meta states.